# Is it possible to record mic input to MP3 playing sound?

Tags: ios, record

I'd like to record my voice during the MP3 playing.
At that time, "MP3 playing" means internal original sound not speaker out.
Is it possible in iOS? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: '"MP3 playing" means internal original sound not speaker out"' — *what?*

Comment: Karaoke? Haven't tried it, but it would be interesting to find out.

Comment: Yes, just like a Karaoke.

Comment: Like a Karaoke, I'd like to mix and record singer's voice and MP3 playing sound (not from speaker out).